# Bootstrap4 popover doc example code doesn't work in codepen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4

I copied the exact same demo code of popover from bootstrap4 documentation to codepen, but it doesn't work. Documents says it needs tether.min.js to get popover to work. I included the tether cdn. Still doesn't work. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.Could anyone help me out?
The demo code is like this:

html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" 
title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's 
very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In order to get Bootstrap4 popover to work, the 'bootstrap.bundle.min.js' is needed. Also, the order to place JQuery and bootstrap.bundle.min.js matters.  JQuery comes first. looks like this:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.js